# su: What does the hyphen with nothing immediately following it mean?

Tags: linux, bash, options

Written as if it were an option, e.g:

`> su - someuser`

Don’t the space breaks apart “-“ and “someuser”? I went through the manpage but didn’t notice an entry for it.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind ! I just found it, i thought it would be on its own but it wasn’t. Man page reads “Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly”.

I’m such a scattered brain—sorry!